# Wagtail Pagination issue with Waypoint Infinite Scroll

Tags: django, infinite-scroll, wagtail, waypoint

I've implemented [Waypoint Infinite Scroll](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/shortcuts/infinite-scroll/) just fine on a regular Page model for art gallery items. Those items can be added to a shop with a checkbox. I then use a Shop page to filter the gallery items that are marked as on sale. For some reason, when the infinite scroll feature seems to trigger just fine on the shop page but no new items are rendered.

I get a 200 response from the server and no errors are logged to the console:

```
[12/Dec/2020 11:40:46] "GET /shop/?page=2 HTTP/1.1" 200 26
```

The page it works with:

```
class Gallery(Page):

    intro = RichTextField(blank=True, help_text="Text for the top of your gallery page. (Optional - recommended to leave empty for a more simplistic look.)")

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [FieldPanel('intro', classname="full")]

    subpage_types = ['InstallationPage']
    # parent_page_types = []

    def get_context(self, request):
        context = super().get_context(request)
        filtered_medium = request.GET.get('medium', None)
        if filtered_medium:
            context['filtered'] = True
            mediums = InstallationMedium.objects.filter(name=filtered_medium)
            installations = InstallationPage.objects.child_of(self).order_by('-date').live().filter(mediums__in=mediums)
        else:
            mediums = InstallationMedium.objects.filter(installationpage__in=InstallationPage.objects.all()).distinct()
            installations = InstallationPage.objects.child_of(self).order_by('-date').live()
        paginator = Paginator(installations, 12)
        page = request.GET.get('page')
        try:
            pagin = paginator.get_page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            pagin = paginator.get_page(1)
        context['installations'] = pagin
        context['mediums'] = mediums
        return context
```

Shop page where it doesn't work:

```
class Shop(RoutablePageMixin, Page):

    ajax_template = "shop/shop_item_ajax.html"

    def get_context(self, request):
        
        context = super().get_context(request)
        shop_items = GalleryItem.objects.filter(Q(direct_sale=True) | Q(external_sale=True)).order_by('latest_revision_created_at')
        paginator = Paginator(shop_items, 12)
        page = request.GET.get('page')

        try:
            items = paginator.get_page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            items = paginator.get_page(1)
        context['shop_items'] = items # shop_items for all items
        for item in items:
            print(item)
        return context
```

main.js:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

var infinite = new Waypoint.Infinite({
      element: $('.infinite-container')[0],
      onBeforePageLoad: function () {
        $('.loader').removeClass('d-none')
      },
      onAfterPageLoad: function ($items) {
        $('.loader').addClass('d-none')
      }
    });
...
```

shop.html:

```
<div class="row justify-content-center justify-content-md-start infinite-container">
    {% for item in shop_items %}
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xl-3 infinite-item">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center text-center">
                <h4><a href="/shop/{{ item.slug }}/">{{ item.title }}</a></h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    {% empty %}
    Nothing for now!
    {% endfor %}
</div>

<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="loader d-none">
        <div class="loader-inner ball-pulse" id="dropin-loading">
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% if shop_items.has_next %}
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <a class="infinite-more-link" href="/shop/?page={{ shop_items.next_page_number }}">More</a>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

Also basic pagination works fine. If I click the hyperlink, it will load page 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was rather simple of course. In the `Shop` class I had added this line

```
ajax_template = "shop/shop_item_ajax.html"
```

from a previous dive into ajax functionality, and that template was an empty file which I never ended up using, so nothing was being rendered. I removed that line and Waypoint Infinite works as advertised.